# Removing Tabs When Exporting Excel to Text

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-editors

When I save an Excel file as a text file every cell has a tab after it.  How do I remove all of these tabs?

I'm looking for a way to do this with a basic text editor, like Notepad, because I need other people to be able to do this as well, and they may only have basic software.

I've tried using the find/replace dialog in Notepad, but when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the Find field, it types nothing and takes me to the next field instead.

Comment: Ur file is "tab de-limited". What would you like to replace these tabs with?

Comment: @Prasanna With nothing at all.

Comment: The answer below should work for u then

Comment: @Prasanna If I try to replace 'tab' it just takes me to the next entry field.  If I just search for them I have to manually remove each one.

Comment: Which editor are u using?

Comment: @Prasanna I'm looking to just use basic Notepad since this needs to be replicated for people who may not know how to use another.

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to provide a pictorial answer to what you need to do in Notepad.

Step-1:

[image]

Step-2:

[image]

Ensure that the **Replace with** box is empty and click the *Replace all* button.

Comment: Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: This works for me.  I know that OP said they wanted to replace it with "nothing at all" but I feel compelled to mention that you can put a space in the *Replace With* field to remove tabs but keep the results from being crammed together... unless that's really the desired output.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with you @guitarpicker

Answer (score 0):

repltab.cmd:

```
powershell .\repltab.ps1
```

powershell, `repltab.ps1`:

```
gc data.txt|%{$_-replace "`t"," "}|sc space.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

After you export the contents of your Excel file into a text file, open the text file in a text editor program like notepad++ or Sublime Text and find tabs and replace with nothing.

Comment: Pressing tab in that editor just moves you to the next entry box.

Comment: My answer was changed. Also there are many text editors that allow for regex find and replace where \t is a tab